# tidy evaluation in dplyr vs base r functions

Tags: r

i tried to summarise the data in dplyr vs base r functions but dont get the expected result, please let me know why

for example i tried the string as a column name in the below example of dplyr and it works

```r
map(c('Sepal.Length'), function(x) {
browser()  
  x <- sym(x)
  iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean=mean( !!x ))
})


[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species     mean
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 setosa      5.01
2 versicolor  5.94
3 virginica   6.59
```

however if i try the same with base r function like aggregate, it fails

```r
map(c('Sepal.Length'), function(x) {
  # browser()  
  x <- sym(x)
  aggregate(!!x ~ Species, data=iris, FUN= mean)
})


Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `!x`:
! invalid argument type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `!!` operator (also known as the injection operator or bang-bang operator or double-bang operator) in a base R formula - it is not a part of base R syntax, but instead is an extension of base R syntax which is specific to certain tidyverse functions. It can only be used inside data-masked arguments, dynamic dots or inside `inject`. Outside of these contexts, you will get an error if you try to use it to defuse quoted symbols. You can read more if you type `` ?rlang::`topic-inject-out-of-context` ``  into your R console.

You can easily build a formula from a string variable using `reformulate` in base R instead:

```r
purrr::map(c('Sepal.Length'), function(x) {
  aggregate(reformulate('Species', x), data = iris, FUN = mean)
})
#> [[1]]
#>      Species Sepal.Length
#> 1     setosa        5.006
#> 2 versicolor        5.936
#> 3  virginica        6.588
```